# A short story about (not) reading Shakespeare in class

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, humor

I read this short story maybe 15-20 years ago, but it might be older than that.

With hindsight, it is pretty prophetic. Even for France, now....

It is about an english teacher (in an english-speaking country, probably the US, maternal not foreign language) in high school. She wants to have her students read a play by Shakespeare.

But there are hitches. Most students of her class are strongly "politically correct", but there is also at least one evangelist. Moreover, the administration of the school does not want to take any risks of conflict with the parents.

So each play she suggests is rejected, from one side or the other. I don't remember precisely the end, but I think that in the entire works of Shakespeare, there is just a **single line** that she is allowed to teach.

Comment: Now I have a dilemma : Clara Diaz Sanchez's post was the one that **convinced** me. But DavidW was first to suggest the same story, though not convincing enough. So which one should I accept ?

Comment: I know the answers both link to the story's ISFDB profile, but I have to say, I don't see how it counts as sci-fi or fantasy. Many of Shakespeare's works count as fantasy, but a story about someone censoring Shakespeare's works through mundane means doesn't sound like sci-fi or fantasy to me.

Comment: @F1Krazy I just checked, it was written in 1988. I last spent a long time in the US ten years earlier, so I don't know how much the situation had changed there since that time, but when I read in in France, probably around the turn of the century, it looked like "sociological fiction **in the future**", which to me counts as SF. Now, I must say, it is almost what you can read in the newspapers. In France, yes. So a prediction fulfilled within two-three decades, but when it was written, still a prediction.

Comment: @F1Krazy It was published in *Asimov's* so obviously Dozois thought it was on-topic.

Comment: Anyone could help me decide whose answer to accept, DavidW's earlier but not convincing enough one, or Clara Diaz Sanchez's later but convinving one ? DavidW did edit his answer, but that was after I read the other one. Hard, hard to decide !

Comment: Always accept the answer that is best regardless of when it came in.

Comment: @F1Krazy It's an extrapolation of present day social behavior to a (near) future. I'd say that qualifies it as science fiction.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots While I was reading the second (convincing) answer, DavidW was already editing his, and the two answers came out identical. The timing was such that **he did not have time to read the other answer**, his editing was in response to my doubts.

Comment: @user14111 Good idea ! But I know how to create a bounty, and I once awarded one just after it had expired, during the "grace period" to an answer that I did not accept, but was still interesting. But how do I award a bonus that is not an expired bounty ?

Comment: @user14111 So it is what I thought: wait for two days so I can start a bounty, after having accepted one answer, and then transfer the bounty to the other one. No more direct way. Fine. I'll use those two days to make up my mind....

Comment: @Bjorn Eriksson It is **definitely** *Ado*, but I want to wait 2 days to start a bounty so I can give it to one answer and "accept" the other one, as uset14111 has suggested

Comment: Hey ! Wait ! How do I now give rep to the two people who answered correctly ? I wanted to check one and make a bounty for the other one, but it waa too early to start a bounty !

Comment: Though the question was closed, I was able to "green check" Clara Diaz Sanchez's answer. But I want to give a bonus to DavidW and now I cannot start the bounty ! It does not seem right to pick randomly one of his answers to another question, start a bonus there  and award it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This sounds like "[Ado](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?40679)", a short story by Connie Willis, first published in 1988. As you recall, it deals with a schoolteacher in a near future USA trying to cover the works of Shakespeare, but the demands of political correctness require him and the school principle to remove all "problematic" language in the plays.

They first try to find a play:

> Trying to figure out which works were still allowed, the teacher and
> principle sifted through the objections:
>
> -The Royal Society for the Divine Rights of Kings objected to *Richard III* because there was no proof that he has killed the princess … they in
> fact objected to all the plays about Kings.
>
> -Angry Woman’s Alliance objected to the *Taming of the Shrew*, *Merry Wives of Windsor*, *Romeo and Juliet*, and *Love’s Labour Lost*.
>
> -The American Bar Associating objected to *The Merchant of Venice* …as did Morticians International due to defaming of the word casket.
>
> -The Sierra Club objected to *As You Like It* because Orlando carves Rosalind’s name into a tree

and so on.

Eventually they settle on *Hamlet*, but have to go through it removing all the objectionable lines, until they are just left with two sentences.

It is included in the Willis anthology "[The Winds of Marble Arch and Other Stories](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?148381)", which is available for loan at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/windsofmarblearc00will/page/288/mode/2up?q=ado).

Comment: Yes it is the right one! Thanks. I'm not sure which to accept (see my comment on my question)

Comment: @Alfred The amazing thing is that DavidW and I answered at almost the exact same time. We jinxed each other...

Comment: Yes, and DavidW updated his post, but after I read yours... Difficult choice !

Comment: There's no rush to accept, take your time! I've included a link to an online version of the story if you want to refresh your memory of it.

Comment: Thanks to your link, I just reread it entirely. I found it just as hilarious as the first time. The last twist about Dalilah being "hoist by her own petard", censured for using "spokesman" instead of "spokesperson" (how can one misspell "person" ????) is just perfect.

Answer (score 9):

This is "[Ado](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?40679)" by Connie Willis.  An English teacher wishes to teach a Shakespeare play to her students; they are forced to settle on *Hamlet*, which they go through line by line but in the end only a short bit of dialog between two guards is left.

> "Well, it may be easier than we think,” she said. "There have been a lot of suits since last year, which takes care of *Macbeth*, *The Tempest*, *Midsummer Night’s Dream*, *The Winter’s Tale*, and *Richard III*."
>
> "Delilah’s been a busy girl,” I said. I fed in the unexpurgated disk and the excise and reformat programs. "I don’t remember there being any witchcraft in *Richard III*.”
>
> She sneezed and grabbed for another Kleenex. "There’s not. That was a slander suit. Filed by his great-great-grand-something. He claims there’s no conclusive proof that Richard III killed the little princes. It doesn’t matter anyway. The Royal Society for the Restoration of Divine Right of Kings has an injunction against all the history plays. What’s the weather supposed to be like?”
>
> "Terrible,” I said. "Warm and sunny.” I called up the catalog and deleted *Henry IV, Parts I and II*, and the rest of her list. "*Taming of the Shrew*?”
> "Angry Women’s Alliance. Also *Merry Wives of Windsor*, *Romeo and Juliet*, and *Love’s Labour’s Lost*.”
>
> "*Othello*? Never mind. I know that one. *Merchant of Venice*? The Anti- Defamation League?”
>
> "No. American Bar Association. And Morticians International. They object to the use of the word 'casket’ in Act III.” She blew her nose.

After deciding on *Hamlet* they go through it line-by-line:

> We worked until five o’clock. The Society for the Advancement of Philosophy considered the line, "There are more things in heaven and earth, Horatio, than are dreamt of in your philosophy,” a slur on their profession. The Actors’ Guild challenged Hamlet’s hiring of non-union employees, and the Drapery Defense League objected to Polonius being stabbed while hiding behind a curtain. "The clear implication of the scene is that the arras is dangerous,” they had written in their brief. "Draperies don’t kill people. People kill people.”

Finally there's only a little bit left:

> I passed out Hamlet and assigned Wendy and Rick to read the parts of Hamlet and Horatio.
>
> " 'The air bites shrewdly; it is very cold,’ ” Wendy read.
>
> "Where are we?” Rick said. I pointed out the place to him. "Oh. 'It is a nipping and an eager air.’ ”
>
> " 'What hour now?’ ” Wendy read.
>
> " 'I think it lacks of twelve.’ ”
>
> Wendy turned her paper over and looked at the back. "That’s it?” she said.

The story was originally published in the January 1980 issue of *Isaac Asimov's Science Fiction Magazine* and you can read it [at the Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/Asimovs_v12n01_1988-01/page/n79/mode/1up).

Comment: Sounds good. But your link does not lead to the full text. Could you give some specific details to help me pinpoint it ?

Comment: Yes it is convincing now, but I read the other convincing answer before, but after your initial post.